# How to print a string centered (vertical and horizontal) in video mode?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm, dosbox

I learn to use **set video mode** and print a string on it.

```
.model small
.stack 200h
.code

org     100h

mulai:
        mov     ax, @data
        mov     ds, ax

; video mode

        xor     ah, ah
        mov     al, 03h
        int     10h

; print string

        mov     ah, 0eh
        mov     al, "!"
        int     10h

end mulai
```

Assembling and linking using `TASM` and `TLINK` :

```
tasm foo.asm
tlink foo
```

**Question**

How I can print a string centered (vertical and horizontal) ?

---

Output :

[image]

Expected output :

```
+-------------------------+
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|            !            |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
+-------------------------+
```

Comment: move the cursor to the center of the screen before printing the char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### When a text video mode is active

For outputting a character at a specific location on the screen, you can set the cursor using the BIOS.SetCursorPosition function 02h. You'll have to specify the column number in the `DL` register, and the row number in the `DH` register. And because the graphics card supports outputting on up to 8 different pages when you're in video mode 03h, you'll have to specify that page in the `BH` register.

The text video mode 03h has 80 columns and 25 rows, therefore the center is at column 40 (28h) and row 12 (0Ch).

```
mov dx, 0C28h  ; Row=12 (in DH), Column=40 (in DL)
mov bh, 0      ; Page=0
mov ah, 02h    ; BIOS.SetCursorPosition
int 10h
```

Hereafter the BIOS.Teletype function will output the character at (40,12) and leave the cursor at (41,12) ready for your next output of a character...

```
mov bh, 0      ; Page=0
mov ax, 0E21h  ; BIOS.Teletype (in AH), Character=33 (in AL)  33 is ASCII of "!"
int 10h
```

### When a graphics video mode is active

Here also, for outputting a character at a specific location on the screen, you can set the cursor using the BIOS.SetCursorPosition function 02h. You'll have to specify the column number in the `DL` register, and the row number in the `DH` register. And because the graphics card supports outputting on just 1 page when you're in video mode 13h, you'll have to specify 0 in the `BH` register.

The graphics video mode 13h has 320 pixels in the horizontal direction and 200 pixels in the vertical direction. A pixel can be shown in any of 256 colors. Although this screen is All Points Addressable (APA), displaying characters is just as easy as in the text video modes. You can use the same output functions.

The graphics video mode 13h has 40 columns and 25 rows, therefore the center is at column 20 (14h) and row 12 (0Ch).

```
mov dx, 0C14h  ; Row=12 (in DH), Column=20 (in DL)
mov bh, 0      ; Page=0
mov ah, 02h    ; BIOS.SetCursorPosition
int 10h
```

Hereafter the BIOS.Teletype function will output the character at (20,12) and leave the cursor at (21,12) ready for your next output of a character...

```
mov bx, 000Fh  ; Page=0 (in BH), Color=15 (in BL)             15 is BrightWhite
mov ax, 0E21h  ; BIOS.Teletype (in AH), Character=33 (in AL)  33 is ASCII of "!"
int 10h
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How I can set to graphic mode in generally?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a graphic mode what you are learning. With [AX=0003h/INT 10h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0069.htm) you have switched VGA to **text mode** 80 characters in 25 lines. You cannot draw graphic in this mode, you can only print text strings or ASCII art or pseudographic characters.

[TELETYPE OUTPUT AH=0Eh/INT 10h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0106.htm) prints only one character. When you want to print "**!**" 80 times, `MOV CX,80` and repeat `INT 10h` CX-times.

In the real **graphic mode**, for instance [AX=0013h/INT 10h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0069.htm#Table10), is the videomemory at `0A000h:0` displayed as 320 pixels in 200 rows (1 byte per pixel). You should define your own font and copy it to videomemory pixel by pixel, when you want to print text strings in graphic mode.

Comment: Oopss.. sorry my bad, edited, this is video mode

Comment: You might want to change your paragraph about the graphic mode 13h. BIOS.Teletype function **does work** just like on any other of the legacy screens. Therefore your first paragraph sentence *"You can print text strings or ASCII art or pseudographic characters only in text mode."* can easily be misread. (because of the *only*).